# How to create a new UIView programmatically in cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I want to create a new UIView on button click programmatically in cocos2d. Kindly help me with some sample code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You have to create a button like-

```
UIButton* myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(30, 70,100,38); //set frame for button

[myButton setTitle:@"subview" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Or you can use CCMenu as a button.

And then write the event handling function-

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
        UIView *myview=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0,320,480)];
        myview.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
        [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:myview];
        [myview release];                   
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote above, the class is called UIView. It's really simple to create a new View. Take a look at this code snippet.

```
-(void)youButtonAction:(id)sender {
   //This method is executed as soon as you button is pressed.
   UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
   [anotherView addSubview:newView];  //Add the newView to another View
   [newView release];
}
```

I hope you got the point. At first you have to create the view, than add it to another view and in the end release it. ;-)

Sandro Meier

Comment: I think he is asking for adding view in cocos2d Scene, not in another view.

Comment: Ah ok. That's possible. ^^So you explained it. :-D