# Add FaceBook Login To Cocos2d Xcode Project

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to add facebook to my ios xcode game. I can add a facebook login button on a single view application like this:

```
FBLoginView *loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];

loginview.frame = CGRectOffset(loginview.frame, 5, 5);
loginview.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:loginview];

[loginview sizeToFit];
```

But when i try and add this to my cocos2d project I get an error on this line:

```
[self.view addSubview:loginview];
```

I have tried adding it as a child but that doesn't work either. How can I add the button to the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `Cocos2D` scenes are not `subclassed` from `UIViews`, you can't directly add a `UIView` as a `subview`.

Try the solution in this post: [How to create a new UIView programmatically in cocos2d?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568424/how-to-create-a-new-uiview-programmatically-in-cocos2d)

The key portion is(iOS<7):

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:myview];
```

For iOS 7, use:

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view]addSubview:myview];
```

Answer (score 4):

[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:myview];

**its working correct but openGLView is deprecated**

You can use:

**[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] myView];**